# can't read filename in windows-server-2012-r2

Tags: php, mysql, glob, windows-server-2012-r2

I tried to grab data, and when I tried in local. It can read the filename. But when I move to window server. It can't read, result is blank. Anybody can give me solution. Thank You !

This First

```
foreach (glob("//192.168.1.6/VersaWorks/*.log")as $log) {  
    echo $log;
}
```

This Second

```
foreach (glob("//192.168.1.13/Job/*.job")as $job) { 
echo $job;
}
```

First Result when i tried in local

```
//192.168.1.6/VersaWorks/Roland VersaWorks.log
```

Second Result when i tried in local

```
 //192.168.1.13/Job/JAKARTA0002.job
```

This when I tried to mapping in drive z:, it's work in my laptop, but in windows server 2012-r2 not work.

```
    foreach (glob("Z://*.log")as $log) { 
    echo $log;
   }
```

But when I tried in drive C: windows server 2012, it's work.

Comment: there's no error, how to  echoed DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR

Comment: When you're fetching from the server, there's no authentication happening which Windows does in the background in the Windows Explorer. However, if you map the drive locally, that *MIGHT* work. Otherwise you're going to have to authenticate to the server first. You're probably going to have to do an LDAP connection.

Comment: yes, if i tried move the file  to drive C: in  local  window server. it work's. but when i tried to get with ip, it not work.

Comment: I meant, try mapping the drive. For example map the server share to your Z: drive.

But you're probably just going to have to do LDAP authentication.

Comment: i was tried to mapping and make drive z. and when i tried in my laptop it work's. but in windows server it's not work.

Comment: Looks like you're going to have to use LDAP authentication in your app then.